# Baofeng UV-B6 transmits no audio

Tags: ht, baofeng, transmission, equipment-troubleshooting, microphone

I have this Baofeng UV-B6 (the same as B5), and after using CHIRP a few times, transmission stopped working. In fact, it starts transmitting, but no voice is sent whatsoever — dead carrier. RX works without any issues.

I tried with restoring default settings (CHIRP backup), [by using "recovery" image](http://www.miklor.com/UVB5/UVB5-Recovery.php), even resetting the radio to factory settings (menu + power on), and got no result. Still nothing.

It seems to me like the radio itself thinks that external mic is plugged in, so it overrides the built-in microphone. That's how I would've described the situation.

Anyone know how to fix this issue? More important — is it worth fixing it?

**EDIT**
Here's the video tutorial on how to fix this issue (read the accepted answer): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BrGo1-uW3k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this happens when you accidentally bend the inside of the jack (inside the radio) with the programming cable (or speaker mic) plug. In general you have to carefully open the radio and bend the contacts back down.

[Miklor](http://www.miklor.com/) has some instructions on opening the radio. There are also some videos of opening the radio on YouTube.

Comment: That came up on my mind. Thank you for the tip, I'll surely try it out.